# Looking for a relatively painless way to offload the email notifications sent from my app

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, web-applications, smtp

I have a web app built on zend that send email notifications for different events (signup, someone follows you etc...).  It is using php mail.  The emails get sent out as part of action hooks that fire at various events.  I am looking for recommendations for a service that will take over the sending of the emails.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: But what's actually the problem with the mail sending? Does it overload your servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we use http://sendgrid.com/ at our shop.

Comment: Signed up.  This is great.  Exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SES or [Sailthru](https://www.sailthru.com/)

I do like sailthru, they can host your email templates, logs of every sent email (so you can resend), open rates, etc. It's a white listing service and their PHP API is easssy to use.

Answer (score 0):

[Postmark](http://www.postmarkapp.com) is quite nice, with a very powerful API.